# C# - Truncating after a position

Tags: c#

I have a double typed variable. This variable stores information that is part of a more complex formula. Importantly, this variable can only include information up to the tenths location, or one decimal position (i.e. 10.1, 100.2, etc). However, when determining this value, it must be calculated such that anything past the tenths location is truncated, not rounded. For instance:

if the value equals 10.44, The variable value should be 10.4.
if the value equals 10.45, The variable value should also be set to 10.4

How do I truncate values in C# with respect to a decimal place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an extension method:

```
public static double RoundDown(this double value, int digits)
{
     int factor = Math.Pow(10,digits);

     return Math.Truncate(value * factor) / factor;
}
```

Then you simply use it like this:

```
double rounded = number.RoundDown(2);
```

Comment: I believe it needs to be a static method in a static class for it to be an Extension method

Comment: Of course, you're right. I added the static keyword. I left out the class declaration as this pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

System.Math.Truncate (d * 10) / 10

Comment: This will truncate to 2 digits

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that by your own:

```
    public static decimal Truncate(decimal value, int decimals)
    {
        if ((decimals < 0) || (decimals > 28))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("decimals", "The number of fractional decimals must be between 0 and 28.");
        }

        decimal integral = Math.Truncate(value);
        decimal fractional = value - integral;
        decimal shift = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimals);

        fractional = Math.Truncate(shift * fractional);
        fractional = fractional / shift;

        return (integral + fractional);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I would probably use Phillippe's answer, if you wanted to avoid scaling the number up (unlikely to be a problem for 1dp), you could:

```
    public static double RoundDown(this double x, int numPlaces)
    {
        double output = Math.Round(x, numPlaces, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        return (output > x ? output - Math.Pow(10, -numPlaces) : output);
    }
```

Comment: That's rounding, not truncating

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you're working with numbers where the precise decimal representation is important, you should use [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) - not `double`.

With `decimal`, you can do something like...

```
decimal d = ...;
d = decimal.Truncate(d*10)/10;
```

If you use a `double` value, your truncated number will not generally be precisely representable - you may end up with excess digits or minor rounding errors.  For example `Math.Truncate((4.1-4.0)*10)` is not 1, but 0.